# how to only select one data base on column value?

Tags: mysql, sql

| name | category | sets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| livingroom pack-A | 15 | 1 |
| livingroom pack-B | 15 | 1 |
| livingroom table | 15 | 0 |
| diningroom pack-A | 16 | 1 |
| diningroom pack-B | 16 | 1 |
| bedroom pack | 17 | 1 |
| bedroom mirror | 17 | 0 |

how to fetch only one items that its "sets" column value is "1", but different category won't effect each other? which means I want c2-15 and c2-16 items both only display one of it (either A or B), and other "sets" value is 0 items will still display normally.

like this:

```
dining room pack-B
living room pack-A
livingroom table
bedroom pack
bedroom mirror
```

Answer (score 3):

For example,

```sql
SELECT ANY_VALUE(name) name, category, ANY_VALUE(sets) sets
FROM tablename
GROUP BY category, CASE WHEN sets THEN 1 ELSE RAND() END
```

or

```sql
SELECT ANY_VALUE(name) name, category, 1 sets
FROM tablename
WHERE sets
GROUP BY category
UNION ALL
SELECT name, category, 0 sets
FROM tablename
WHERE NOT sets
```

PS. The last variant must be more fast.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, but the problem is in my original sql code I also have "group by name" (because I have multiple data is same name but different detail), if I use "group by category, name", it won't display the same result like your code, it'll display more than one item in same category where its "sets" is "1"